# how to add a table row as a template using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to add a row dynamically to a table. I would like to reuse the row in a few tables.

I tried doing this with a directive and by using `ng-include` but neither option worked as I expected.

Basically, this is what I did:

```
myapp.directive('myRow', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        scope : { mytitle : '@mytitle'},
        template : '<tr><td class="mystyle">{{mytitle}}</td></tr>' 
    }
});
```

and in html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <my-row></my-row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `<tr>` element gets drawn but ends up *outside* the `<table>` element in the dom.

Is there a simple way to include table rows using angularjs?

Comment: You have a typo `<tr></tr>` it must be `</td></tr>` You cannot have 2 root elements in the template. Just check your console, you will get all kinds of clues there itself. http://plnkr.co/edit/pCNbci?p=preview

Comment: thanks! I just typed it into SO. Real code is correct.

Comment: That is because browser it throwing it out. you cannot have anything else as a child of tbody. make your directive attribute directive and you should be good to go. Check my demo.

Comment: Just check my demo in chrome.. it will be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you have invalid html structure because of the presence of the custom element `my-row` inside `tbody`. You can only have `tr` inside tbody. So the browser is throwing your directive element out of the table even before angular has a chance to process it.So when angular processes the directive, it processes the element outside the table.

In order to fix this, change your directive to be attribute restricted directive from element restricted.

```
   .directive('myRow', function () {
     return {
        restrict : 'A',
        replace : true,
        scope : { mytitle : '@mytitle'},
        template : '<tr><td class="mystyle">{{mytitle}}<td></tr>' 
     }
```

and use it as:-

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <tr my-row mytitle="Hello I am Title"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pCNbci?p=preview)**

Comment: @chriskelly Please see my answer. I have reworded.

Comment: Many thanks! This is a clear explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Correct if I am wrong but this approach does not work if someone wants to insert two or more rows replacing the current row.
Following thread addresses this issue by replacing the tr withing link function.

[AngularJs while replacing the table row - changing html from compile function but scope is not getting linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376054/angularjs-while-replacing-the-table-row-changing-html-from-compile-function-bu)